# How to stop the AJAX content to disappear from the HTML Div element after changing HTML select option?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an HTML select option element, where the options come from PHP:

```
<select class="forms" id ="selectGroup" name="taskOption"  onchange="openGroupDrivers()">
                <option selected = "selected">  Select Driver Group</option>
                <?php
                $drGroup = getAvailableDriverGroups();
                for ($x = 0; $x < count($drGroup); $x++)
                    echo '<option value="' . $drGroup[$x]['name'] . '">' . $drGroup[$x]['name'] . '</option>';
                ?>
            </select>
```

The change of this select option calls the JavaScript AJAX `function openGroupDrivers():`

```
function openGroupDrivers() {
    a1 = 1;       
    var group = document.getElementById('selectGroup').value;
    var queryString = "?group=" + group;
    $.ajax({url: "getDriverList.php" + queryString, success: function (result) {
            $("#groupDrivers").html(result);
        }});        
}
```

Inside the getDriverList.php I have 2 Div elements, first is the list of PHP content, and the second is empty at first:

```
$drivers = getDrivers($wialon_api);
    $driverCount = (count ($drivers['id']));
    $i = 0;
    echo '<br> <div>  <div  id = "wholeList">';
        for (; $i < $driverCount; $i++)
                {

                    $objectID = $drivers['id'][$i];
                    if (in_array($objectID,$driverGroup)  )
                    {
                        echo '<li> <input type="checkbox" class ="chk" name ="check[]" onchange = "add()" id ="'. $drivers['id'][$i].'"  value ="'. $drivers['name'][$i].'">';
                        echo "<label>".$drivers['name'][$i]."</label>";     
                        echo '</li>';   
                    }

                }       

    echo '</div>';          


?>


<div id = "selectedList">




</div>

</div>
```

Inside those Div elements I also have buttons to add and remove the list elements from the first Div to the second:

```
function add() {
    $("#wholeList").find("input:checked").each(function (i, ob) {
        $(ob).attr("onchange", "remove()");
        $(ob).prop('checked', false);
        ($(ob).closest('li')).appendTo('#selectedList');
    });
};

function remove() {
    $("#selectedList").find("input:checked").each(function (i, ob) {
        $(ob).attr("onchange", "add()");
        $(ob).prop('checked', false);
        ($(ob).closest('li')).appendTo('#wholeList');
    });
};
```

But after I change the value in select option, the second Div `"selectedList"` with added elements gets empty again. I want it to save the content dynamically somewhere and append to the same Div element when AJAX call finishes processing. I have tried to get and append this content to `"selectedList"` inside the function `openGroupDrivers()` , but the content gets written and then disappears after AJAX is finished. Where and when should I save and write this content? Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide only the relevant code? (i.e: remove all unnecessary attributes from the output **HTML**). Thanks

Comment: Yes, of course, I have removed unnecessary attributes

Comment: Is this so difficult? I just don't have an experience with AJAX and JavaScript